# Input date текущий день

Tags: javascript, html

Как сделать, чтобы в поле появлялся текущий день

```
<div class="formright">
    <label for="name">Join date:</label>
    <input type="date" id="myDate" name="join_date" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Присвойте свойству [`valueAsDate`](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#dom-input-valueasdate) поля ввода нужное значение, то есть текущую дату:

```js
document.getElementById('myDate').valueAsDate = new Date();
```

```html
<div class="formright">
  <label for="name">Join date:</label>
  <input type="date" id="myDate" name="join_date" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Думаю это вам поможет.

```js
var fullDateTime = new Date();
var getNormalDate = function(date){
  var day = date.getDate();
  var month = date.getMonth() + 1;
  var year = date.getFullYear();
  return month + '/' + day + '/' + year;
 };
document.getElementById('myDate').value = getNormalDate(fullDateTime);
```

```html
<div class="formright">
    <label for="name">Join date:</label>
    <input type="date" id="myDate" name="join_date" />
</div>
```

Comment: не работает код

Comment: Не может такого быть, на кнопке выполнить же работает. Это вы его видимо не правильно используете у себя в коде

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/2kvxqfc.png

Comment: Ваша ссылка на картинку не открывается... (((

Answer (score 0):

```js
Data = new Date();
Hour = Data.getHours();
Minutes = Data.getMinutes();
Seconds = Data.getSeconds();

// Вывод
document.write("Текущее время: " + Hour + ":" + Minutes + ":" + Seconds);
```

Comment: Вроде это немножко не то — так вы получите текущее время, а не дату, к тому же результат запишется в виде строки в документ, а автор вроде хочет чтобы результат записался в поле ввода `<input>`

Comment: именно так в input и дату